# PySpark: How to Split String into Character from a String Column and Get Count of Occurrence for Each of Them

Tags: pyspark

I have the table call payment and field call 'hist'. It has millions of rows, each row can have unto 24 alphanumeric values. I need to split each rows by character and count the total occurrence of them using PySpark. Please help

[Something Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OESC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this operation will be hard to do in native Spark, so I suggest using a  UDF approach. You can focus on how to do it with Pandas, and then port it to Spark through [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/). There is a bit of a catch though in that UDF is applied per partition so we may need another aggregate.

Example below:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

items = ["abacc12", "aaaacccnnnn", "aaasssaba", "a12baaaa"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"item": items})

def logic(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    all_letters = ''.join(df["item"].values)
    res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(Counter(all_letters)), 
                                 orient="index").reset_index()
    res.columns=["item", "count"]
    return res
```

This will already work on Pandas if you do:

```py
logic(df.copy())
```

To bring it to Spark easily, we can use Fugue:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from fugue import transform

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
transform(sdf, logic, schema="item:str,count:int", engine=spark).show()
```

and this function will apply on Spark. The schema is a requirement for Spark UDF so Fugue has a simpler representation of that.

The only issue is this runs per partition so you will get duplicate keys:

```
+----+-----+
|item|count|
+----+-----+
|   a|    2|
|   b|    1|
|   c|    2|
|   1|    1|
|   2|    1|
|   a|    4|
|   c|    3|
|   n|    4|
|   a|    5|
|   s|    3|
|   b|    1|
|   a|    5|
|   1|    1|
|   2|    1|
|   b|    1|
+----+-----+
```

But from here you just need to aggregate:

```py
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
sdf = transform(sdf, logic, schema="item:str,count:int", engine=spark)
sdf.groupBy("item").sum("count").show()
```

And you get:

```
+----+----------+
|item|sum(count)|
+----+----------+
|   c|         5|
|   1|         2|
|   b|         3|
|   a|        16|
|   2|         2|
|   n|         4|
|   s|         3|
+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be very easy if you are able to use `explode` to unpivot the characters into rows - It depends on the size of the data and your cluster's / machine's memory.

Here's an example using *first 2 values of `hist`*.

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('abacc12',), ('aaaacccnnnn',)]).toDF(['hist']). \
    withColumn('hist_chars', func.split('hist', '')). \
    withColumn('hist_chars_rows', 
               func.explode(func.expr('filter(hist_chars, x -> x != "")'))
               ). \
    groupBy('hist_chars_rows'). \
    agg(func.count('*').alias('char_count')). \
    orderBy(func.desc('char_count')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---------------+----------+
# |hist_chars_rows|char_count|
# +---------------+----------+
# |a              |6         |
# |c              |5         |
# |n              |4         |
# |1              |1         |
# |b              |1         |
# |2              |1         |
# +---------------+----------+
```